# Bugg while installing earthengine-api

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to install earthengine-api in Debian to have access to the CLI but have issues when running it.

Currentelly using this code:

> pipx install earthengine-api

But when running get the following:

> earthengine

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/c/Users/user/.local/bin/earthengine", line 5, in 
from ee.cli.eecli import main
File "/mnt/c/Users/user/.local/pipx/venvs/earthengine-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ee/cli/eecli.py", line 17, in 
from ee.cli import commands
File "/mnt/c/Users/user/.local/pipx/venvs/earthengine-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ee/cli/commands.py", line 1912
CopyCommand,
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Has anyone had the same issue and knows how to fix this?